# Merging two views in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two views in below format.

```
ProductId Version IsAvailable
123       1       Yes
124       1       No
125       1       Yes
126       1       No

ProductId Version IsShippable
123       1       Yes
124       1       Yes
125       1       No
127       1       Yes
```

I need to merge these two tables into a single table:

```
ProductId Version IsAvailable IsShippable
123       1       Yes         Yes
124       1       No          Yes
125       1       Yes         No
126       1       No          Null
127       1       Null        Yes
```

How can I write the query to achieve this?

Comment: You should show us the original source data and the code for the two views.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sure, but how does that help?

Comment: Because a view is the product of a query.  Unless you used the term "view" to mean "table?"  Please clarify whether you are showing us tables or views on top of tables.

Comment: These are views but both the views and tables work in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use full outer join between 2 views like below:

```
select a.ProductId, a.Version, IsAvailable, IsShippable 
from tableA a
full outer join tableB b on a.productid =b.productid and a.version=b.version
```

Comment: Doesn't it just join the common rows?

Comment: But in this case, the product id is coming null for rows that are not present in tableA.